# what does " . ~ . - " mean in lmer?

Tags: r

I am trying to understand a piece of code testing for the likelihood ratio between two models.

```
mod <- lmer(Proportion~(Trained*Level)+Gender+Race+Scan+(1|ID), df_RSW_TN)
mod_interaction <- update(mod, . ~ . - Trained:Level)

anova(mod, mod_interaction)
```

My questions are:

1. what does `(Trained*Level)` mean?
2. What does `. ~ . - Trained:Level` mean?

Answer (score 2):

The original model formula contains `Trained*Level`, which will fit the "main effects" for `Trained` and `Level`, as well as their interaction `Trained:Level`. So `Trained*Level = Trained + Level + Trained:Level`.

The `update()` call subtracts `Trained:Level`, so this interaction effect is removed from the updated model, while keeping the main effects. The dots `.` represent the existing terms, so using `.` on the left hand side of the `~` keeps the original dependent variable `Proportion`, and using `.` on the right hand side keeps all the other predictors.